# SSH over local unix socket

Tags: ssh, proxy, https, sockets

I'm trying to make a tunneling application to use SSH over a HTTPS connection, with a custom client and server at each end, where the custom client opens a unix socket that can communicate with the SSH server on the other end. The problem is I'm not sure how to get ssh to open a connection over the unix socket rather than specifiying a host and port. Is this possible or are there any command line arguments that can be set to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the ProxyCommand [ProxyCommand](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) option in the docs for ssh. It allows you to use pretty much anything that can redirect to stdio.

Answer (score 0):

In your ~/.ssh/config file you want to add an entry like so

```
Host theDestination 
  Hostname www.theDestination.com
  ProxyCommand ssh me@proxyBox.com nc %h %p
  User me
```

This will automatically tunnel your connection through proxybox.com to theDestination. One thing to note is that you will need to make sure you have nc installed on the proxyBox.